# Symfony API Plateform: How to get application/json format from a Postman request

Tags: postman

When I send a request to my CRUD API using API Plateform, I receive the following

```
{
    "@context": "/symfony_test_server/public/apip/contexts/User",
    "@id": "/symfony_test_server/public/apip/users",
    "@type": "hydra:Collection",
    "hydra:member": [
        {
            "@id": "/symfony_test_server/public/apip/users/1",
            "@type": "User",
            "id": 1,
            "email": "test@gmail.com",
            "password": "my_password"
        }
    ],
    "hydra:totalItems": 1
}
```

I want to have

```
   {
        "@id": "/symfony_test_server/public/apip/users/1",
        "@type": "User",
        "id": 1,
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "password": "my_password"
    }
```

as I get when using the web api and specify

Media type
-> application/json
Controls Accept header.

I have put in request header:
Accept-Language: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

but it desn't work.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
In postman the Accept was set automatically but not editable.
I added new header entry Accept with application/json and it worked.
Hope this help.